# Window.Print in mobile browser is printing the whole window and extra blank page is coming

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, printing

i have written javascript to print the div content in the Window.print and it is working fine with the desktop browser.
But when i open the web application in the mobile browser and try to print , it is printing the whole window with the menus also, and not the div only.
Also an extra blank page is coming along with the page.

Can some one help me why the strange behavior is with the mobile browser.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using
209mm * 297mm A4
And cooperate css page-breaak-before:always
The extra space is filled with blank